# Which representation of CNN feature maps is correct?

Tags: deep-learning, image-classification, convolutional-neural-network

When I extract my features from my CNN, it doesn't look like this:

[image: This]

And those pictures are not just representation. From [this article](https://becominghuman.ai/what-exactly-does-cnn-see-4d436d8e6e52) it can be seen that these features are actual extracted features from real CNN.

However, the features that I extracted look exactly like this:

[image: This]

Why is this representation not like the first picture? Is it the correct one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you are comparing like with like.

In the left-most panel of the first image, you are seeing the **weights** in each kernel (one channel from one convolutional layer). These are yellow in the figure below. The size of the kernels is determined by the hyperparameters of the network; they might have a size like 3 × 3 or 31 × 31. I'm not 100% certain about the other two panels; the right-most looks more like convolutional products than filters.

In the second, you are certainly looking at the **activations** when given a particular input example. These images are the result of convolving the input with the kernels; this part is pink in the figure below. Their size depends on the input image size, the kernel size, and the convolution parameters.

From the article you linked to:

[image: Cartoon of image convolution]

Comment: But people are not saying those are kernels. Those are feature maps. https://www.google.com/search?q=high+level+vs+low+level+features&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiEnq3ol-n4AhW7XvEDHaOsAAcQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1536&bih=722&dpr=1.25#imgrc=7INAezm5fiTqZM

Comment: I agree it's likely the right-most panel in the first figure you posted shows feature maps, but I'm pretty sure the elements of the first panel, and I believe the second as well, are the learned filters.